# Create instances in nested generics for TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm developing app using Angular 4. In my code, i would like create an instance from nested generic class as following code:

```
export class Page<T>
{
    constructor(c: { new(): T; }){
       this.FilterData = new c();
    }
    TotalItems: number;
    PageSize: number;
    CurrentPage: number;
    TotalPage: number;
    FilterData: T;
}

export class Filter<T>
{
    constructor(c: { new(): T; })
    {
        this.AdvanceData = new c();
    }
    AdvanceData: T
    IsAdvance: boolean;
    OrderMeThod: string;
    OrderBy: string;
    KeyWord: string;
}
export class Client
{
Name:string;
}
```

And I don't know how can I initial object from  `Page<Filter<Client>>` in which `Filter` and `Client` are initialed in constructor. I have tried such as: `new Page<Filter<Client>>();` but it didn't work.
Kindly help me to resolve that problem. Thanks

Comment: You can't. The type system doesn't exist at runtime, and therefore the generic constraints are also absent. Why don't you just pass instances to the different constructors? Is there a reason for passing the classes?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My problem is resolved by below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `new`, have the function you're passing return the new instance.
Example:

```
interface Generator<T> {
    generate(): T
}

export class Page<T> {
    constructor(c: Generator<T>) {
        this.FilterData = c.generate();
    }

    TotalItems: number;
    PageSize: number;
    CurrentPage: number;
    TotalPage: number;
    FilterData: T;
}

export class Filter<T> {
    constructor(c: Generator<T>) {
        this.AdvanceData = c.generate();
    }

    AdvanceData: T;
    IsAdvance: boolean;
    OrderMeThod: string;
    OrderBy: string;
    KeyWord: string;
}

export class Client {
    Name: string;
}

const clientGenerator: Generator<Client> = {
    generate: () => new Client()
};

const filterGenerator: Generator<Filter<Client>> = {
    generate: () => new Filter(clientGenerator)
};

const pageOfFilterOfClient: Page<Filter<Client>> = new Page(filterGenerator);
```

Comment: Adding the 3rd level (of the `Page`) makes it more interesting, and that's what the question is about

Comment: @Nitzan Tommer: Thank for your following my question.

Comment: @Seaskyways: It work for me. Thank a lot. I thought that it like C# or Java